# Problems with Python's "if not in"

Tags: python, python-3.x, notin

I am writing the following code and am facing a frustrating problem, and I have not been able to solve it after being stuck with it for two days.

This is the simplified code:

```
def crawl_web(url, depth):
    toCrawl = [url]
    crawled = ['https://index.html']
    i = 0
    while i <= depth:
        interim = []
        for x in toCrawl:
            if x not in toCrawl and x not in crawled and x not in interim:
                print("NOT IN")
            crawled.append(x)
        toCrawl = interim
        i += 1
    return crawled

print(crawl_web("https://index.html", 1))
```

The outcome I expect should be just:

```
['https://index.html']
```

But somehow, the "if not in" does not work and keeps giving me this as the output:

```
['https://index.html','https://index.html']
```

Comment: You append to `crawled` *regardless*. Did you mean to indent `crawled.append()` to be part of the `if` statement?

Comment: It performs the loop twice for `depth=1`. `i <= 1` is `True` when `i == 0` and when `i == 1`.

Comment: actually i realize i wrote the simplified code wrongly, should i rewrite it here or post another question with my corrected simplified code?

Answer (score 2):

The `crawled.append` is called no matter what the if statement does, because it's on the same indentation level as the if statement. You need to move it inside.

```
def crawl_web(url, depth):
    toCrawl = [url]
    crawled = ['https://index.html']
    i = 0
    while i <= depth:
        interim = []
        for x in toCrawl:
            if x not in toCrawl and x not in crawled and x not in interim:
                print("NOT IN")
                crawled.append(x)
        toCrawl = interim
        i += 1
    return crawled

print(crawl_web("https://index.html", 1))
```